# Stack in data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am new to data structures.I tried to enter 5 characters and reverse it using pop() function. but value for last index in the array is displayed as null. Can anyone please explain the reason?

**Stack Class:**

```
package stack;

public class Stack {
    
    int top = 0;
    String stack[] = new String[5];
    
    public void push(String val) {
        
        if(top >= 4) {
            
            System.out.println("Overflow Condition");
            
        }
        
        else {
            
            stack[top] = val;
        
            System.out.println("new value for index"+top+" " +"is"+" "+stack[top]);
            
            top++;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public void pop() {
        
        String output ;
        
        if(top == -1) {
            
            System.out.println("Underflow Condition");
        }
        
        else {
            
            
            for(int i= top; i >= 0; i--) {
            
            output = stack[top];
            
            System.out.println("Removed Index:"+" "+(top+1)+"is"+ output);
            top--;
            
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public void peek() {
        
        String output;
        
        if(top >= 4) {
            
            System.out.println("Overflow Condition");
        }
        
        else {
            
            output = stack[top];
            
        }
        
    }   
    
}
```

**Main Program:**

```
package stack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackHome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Stack obj = new Stack();
        
        String arr[] = new String[5];
        
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        
            System.out.println("Value to add for stack");
            String value = inp.next();
            
            arr[i] = value;
            
            obj.push(arr[i]);
        }
        
        obj.pop();
        //obj.peek();
        
    }

}
```

**inputs**

> Value to add for stack
> a
> new value for index0 is a
> Value to add for stack
> b
> new value for index1 is b
> Value to add for stack
> c
> new value for index2 is c
> Value to add for stack
> d
> new value for index3 is d
> Value to add for stack
> e

**outputs**

> Overflow Condition
> Removed Index: 4is null
> Removed Index: 3is d
> Removed Index: 2is c
> Removed Index: 1is b
> Removed Index: 0is a

Comment: Why do you remove multiple elements in the `pop()`-method?

Comment: Hello @dan1st I just tried to use pop() method to remove all the values i added to stack using push() method.

Comment: pop() is intended to remove the element on the top of the stack.

Comment: @dan1st Yes. But in the pop() function i decremented top using top-- . is that wrong??

Comment: Yes but why in a for loop? Apart from that, why do you check for `-1` in the pop method and not 0?

Comment: @dan1st i thought that i could use it for string reverse like when i am entering "abcd" as input i wanted to reverse it as "dcba " that's why i used a for loop in pop() function.

Comment: Just set the element of eith index `top` to `null` and decrement `top`, once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out a couple of changes to simplify your code.

1. You do not need to create a new `array` in your `main()` method since you've already created the `array` (to be used as a `stack`) in the `Stack` class.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
       Stack obj = new Stack();
       //this loop is for pushing elements into the stack
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           System.out.println("Value to add for stack");
           String value = inp.next();
           //you only need to call the push() method to push the element into the array created in the Stack class.
           obj.push(value);
       }
       //this loop is for popping the elements from the stack
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           System.out.println("Value to remove from stack");
           //you just need to call the pop() method to pop an element from the stack 
           obj.pop();
       }
       inp.close();
   }
   ```
2. Your `pop()` method doesn't require a `for` loop because its only job is to remove an element. You can run a loop in the `main()` to pop elements one by one as I've shown above. So your `pop()` method can be modified as below:

   ```
   public String pop() {
       if (top == 0) {
           System.out.println("Underflow Condition");
       }
       else { //no need of for loop here.
               top--;
               String output = stack[top];
               System.out.println("Removed Index:" + " " + (top + 1) + "is" + output);
               return output;
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

**Note:** Once all elements have been pushed into the `stack`, value of `top` will be 5 which is the `length` of the array so you need to decrement the value of `top` first using `top--` so that `top` points to the last index of the array and then you can return the popped element.

Input/Output shown below:

```
Value to add for stack
a b c d e
new value for index0 is a
Value to add for stack
new value for index1 is b
Value to add for stack
new value for index2 is c
Value to add for stack
new value for index3 is d
Value to add for stack
new value for index4 is e
Value to remove from stack
Removed Index: 5ise
Value to remove from stack
Removed Index: 4isd
Value to remove from stack
Removed Index: 3isc
Value to remove from stack
Removed Index: 2isb
Value to remove from stack
Removed Index: 1isa
```

I hope this answers your query.